# Link two tables in dynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a Table A and a Table B on DynamoDB.

Table A:
"Primary key": String,
"name" String,

Table B:
"Primary Key": String,
"List of Primary keys(String) of Table A": List

On deleting an item in Table A, I need to remove all the primary keys in the Lists present in Table B.
Is there any effective mechanism to do so?

Thanks

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is defined as relational integrity. It is a concept used by relational databases that assures that relational information is always in the correct state. One information that depends on other will never be in an incorrect state.

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. As per design, it does not assure relational integrity. The people that designed DynamoDB choosed do not guarantee relational integrity to be able to deliver better performance and better availability (using distributed nodes).

This means that, if you want to assure relational integrity in your application based on DynamoDB, you'll need to implement it in your code. So your application must remove the information from the two tables.

Comment: Or maybe you should not use DynamoDB here at all. I don't think you can get what you need without full scan of table B, which is a very expensive operation for DDB.